# How to match a "match" expression?

Tags: coq, ltac

I am trying to write a rule for hypotheses, formulated with a help of `match` construction:

```coq
Goal forall x:nat, (match x with | 1 => 5 | _ => 10 end = 5 -> x = 1)%nat.
intros.

x : nat
H : match x with
    | 0%nat => 10%nat
    | 1%nat => 5%nat
    | S (S _) => 10%nat
    end = 5%nat
============================
 x = 1%nat
```

How can I match such hypotheses ? The following straight forward method fails:

```coq
match goal with
  |[H:match ?e with | ?a => ?x | ?b => ?y | ?c => ?z end = ?b] => idtac
end.

> Syntax error: 'end' expected after [branches] (in [match_constr]).
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pattern-matching on `match` statements is somewhat weird.

The first thing you should know is that, inside Coq, there's no such thing as a `match` on several variables or with deep matching: everything is translated in terms of simpler `match` statements. Thus, the term you wrote is actually syntax sugar for the following term:

```coq
match x with
| 0 => 10
| S x' =>
  match x' with
  | 0 => 5
  | S x'' => 10
  end
end
```

which is what Coq is hinting at when it prints your proof state. The problem is that this syntax sugar doesn't work on Ltac patterns: thus, when writing an Ltac pattern that mentions a `match`, you should always try to match it as if it were a one-level `match`.

The second problem is that you can't bind the *pattern* part of a `match`: something like

```coq
match goal with
| H : match ?x => _ | ?y => _ end = 5 |- _ => (* ... *)
end
```

doesn't really make sense in Ltac.

You have two choices for solving your problem, then:

1. Write down the `match` you expect with the exact list of constructors of your type on the pattern part, e.g.

   ```coq
   match goal with
   | H : match x with 0 => _ | S _  => _ end = 5 |- _ => (* ... *)
   end
   ```
2. Use the special `match (* ... *) with _ => _ end` syntax, which matches *any* `match` whatsoever:

   ```coq
   match goal with
   | H : match x with _ => _ end = 5 |- _ => (* ... *)
   end
   ```

Often, as in your case, one still wants to consider *all* branches of `match`, including deep ones. This idiom often comes in handy in that case:

```coq
repeat match goal with
| H : match ?x with _ => _ end = _ |- _ =>
  destruct x; try solve [inversion H]
end.
```